# What are some options to handle a scheduled task based on a given datetime in the database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

Im using react and node.js

Im trying to build a site that has multiple countdown timers where an user can join in before it hits 0. These countdown timers are displayed based on a pre-set datetime value in the database.  When the time hits 0 (datetime is reached) i need that specific timer to become disabled and trigger a function to send out something (like an email) to all those that entered.

I tried looking around but im not sure whats best used for this (must be reliable). I saw cron-scheduler, cron, cron-node etc but maybe im looking at it from the wrong angle... The only requirements are that it needs to trigger at the given datetime and send out a message (like an email, seperately).

Usually timers run for a couple days to maximum a week

Answer (score 0):

We use Django and Celery for our backend serving our APIs. For scheduled tasked we use [django-celery-beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). We are running Postgresql for the database and django-celery-beat includes all of the models for the tasks and includes cron.